# Parse string for matching substrings and replace with data

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails-4, substring

Let's say I have some text in rails:

```
text = "A bunch of data goes in here: %@user.name%@, %@user.email%@, %@company.name%@, %@company.state%@ and then some other information as well"
```

I am looking for the best way to parse through that text looking for all substrings between %@ and another %@ in order to replace it with actual data. The text should not anticipate that data will be in any particular order and it should ideally be able to turn the substrings into references to local variables that match the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [String#scan](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/patternmatching.html) method.

For your case in particular, the regex I used to match was: /(\%\@.*?\%\@)/

```
text = "A bunch of data goes in here: %@user.name%@, %@user.email%@, %@company.name%@, %@company.state%@ and then some other information as well"

regex = /(\%\@.*?\%\@)/

#here's the one line version
text.scan(regex).each {|match| text.sub!(match[0], eval(match[0].gsub(/[\%\@]/, '')))}

#Here's the more organized version
text.scan(regex).each do |match| 
  current_match = match[0]
  replacement_var = current_match.gsub(/[\%\@]/, '')
  text.sub!(current_match, eval(replacement_var))
end

puts text
```

Comment: That assumes the data to be substituted will always be in the same order... if your string has email before name, say, that breaks.

Comment: Right. The way the substitution will happen was not specified. I just showed a way to iterate through the tokens, so with a block the user can adjust his way to make the substitutions. Should not be hard.

Comment: Except for the fact that I'm applying this to dynamic, user-generated templates that are potentially dozens of pages and the information being input crosses several models with dozens of attributes each, this is a cool answer. I'll update my question.

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves your problem @topher. It can help more people in the future...

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "A bunch of data goes in here: %@user.name%@, %@user.email%@, %@company.name%@, %@company.state%@ and then some other information as well"


placeholder = text[/\%\@.*?\%\@/]

while placeholder

  case placeholder
  when "%@user.name%@"
    text.sub!(/\%\@.*?\%\@/,"Steve")
  when "%@user.email%@"
    text.sub!(/\%\@.*?\%\@/,"steve@example.com")
  when "%@company.name%@"
    text.sub!(/\%\@.*?\%\@/,"Wayne Industries")
  when "%@company.state%@"
    text.sub!(/\%\@.*?\%\@/,"Gotham")
  else
    text.sub!(/\%\@.*?\%\@/,"unknown")
  end
  placeholder = text[/\%\@.*?\%\@/]
end
```